# How can I present popup from the selected text frame using Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My idea is to present popup near the selected text, after user presses context menu item. Code looks like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "Test",
    title: "Test",
    type: 'normal',
    contexts: ['selection'],
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (item, tab) {
});
```

In the listener neither item or tab have any info about the place, or frame where this text is. I've also tried to access it via `window.getSelection();`, but didn't succeed - selection doesn't contain the info also.

The final goal is to present some piece of HTML from the point of selected text

Comment: You need a *content script* to access the web page. AFAICT this task should have many existing answers in StackOverflow.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I spent about 4 hours yesterday fighting it - no results yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the necessary permissions for the contextMenu in `manifest.json`?

```
"permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ],
```

Comment: I don't remember what I did but eventually, it worked. it could have been permissions issue though - I can accept the answer